# How to implement video recording in android with smallest possible file size?

Tags: android, android-camera

I followed this documentation on how to implement video recording (in my case, I implemented it in a Fragment)

```
static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html

However, I noticed that 30 seconds of recording is around 40mb. I tried an app with video recording and its 30 seconds is just around 7mb. I noticed that the width and height of that one is 720x480.

I would like to ask how to implement such.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement your own `VideoRecorder` so that you can modify as per your own requirement.

set video resolution,

```
mVideoRecorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);
```

set Max Duration,

```
mVideoRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000);
```

Try this

`videorecord.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoRecorder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`VideoRecorderExample.java`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class VideoRecorderExample extends Activity implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public static final String IS_FRONT_CAMERA = "FRONT_CAMERA";
    private static final String TAG = VideoRecorderExample.class.getSimpleName();
    private Boolean mRecording = false;
    private Boolean isFrontCamera = false;
    private VideoView mVideoView = null;
    private MediaRecorder mVideoRecorder = null;
    private Camera mCamera;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videorecord);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoRecorder);

    isFrontCamera = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(IS_FRONT_CAMERA, true);

    final SurfaceHolder holder = mVideoView.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        startRecording(holder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                           int height) {
    Log.e(TAG, "W x H = " + width + "x" + height);
    }

    private void stopRecording() throws Exception {
    mRecording = false;
    if (mVideoRecorder != null) {
        mVideoRecorder.stop();
        mVideoRecorder.release();
        mVideoRecorder = null;
    }
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.reconnect();
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    try {
        stopRecording();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDestroy();

    }

    private void startRecording(SurfaceHolder holder) throws Exception {
    if (mVideoRecorder != null) {
        mVideoRecorder.stop();
        mVideoRecorder.release();
        mVideoRecorder = null;
    }
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.reconnect();
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    String uniqueOutFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".3gp";

    try {
        if (isFrontCamera) {
            mCamera = Camera.open(1);
        } else {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        }

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.unlock();

        mVideoRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mVideoRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mVideoRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mVideoRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(20);
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mVideoRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
        mVideoRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
        mVideoRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000);
        mVideoRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        mVideoRecorder.setOutputFile(uniqueOutFile);
        mVideoRecorder.prepare();
        mVideoRecorder.start();
        mRecording = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

For camera2.

Try this code it will supported with camera2.

```
public class Camera2VideoFragment extends Fragment
    implements View.OnClickListener, FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    private static final int SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES = 90;
    private static final int SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES = 270;
    private static final SparseIntArray DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private static final SparseIntArray INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    private static final String TAG = "Camera2VideoFragment";
    private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

    private static final String[] VIDEO_PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
    };

    static {
    DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    static {
    INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 270);
    INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 180);
    INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 90);
    INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 0);
    }

    /**
     * An {@link AutoFitTextureView} for camera preview.
     */
    private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;

    private Button mButtonVideo;

    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;

    private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession;


    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
        = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                          int width, int height) {
        openCamera(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                            int width, int height) {
        configureTransform(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    }

    };

    private Size mPreviewSize;


    private Size mVideoSize;

    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    private boolean mIsRecordingVideo;

    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;

    /**
     * A {@link Semaphore} to prevent the app from exiting before closing the camera.
     */
    private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);

    /**
     * {@link CameraDevice.StateCallback} is called when {@link CameraDevice} changes its status.
     */
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        startPreview();
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        if (null != mTextureView) {
            configureTransform(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null != activity) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

    };
    private Integer mSensorOrientation;
    private String mNextVideoAbsolutePath;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;
    private Surface mRecorderSurface;

    public static Camera2VideoFragment newInstance() {
    return new Camera2VideoFragment();
    }

    /**
     * In this sample, we choose a video size with 3x4 aspect ratio. Also, we don't use sizes
     * larger than 1080p, since MediaRecorder cannot handle such a high-resolution video.
     *
     * @param choices The list of available sizes
     * @return The video size
     */
    private static Size chooseVideoSize(Size[] choices) {
    for (Size size : choices) {
        if (size.getWidth() == size.getHeight() * 4 / 3 && size.getWidth() <= 1080) {
            return size;
        }
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable video size");
    return choices[choices.length - 1];
    }

    /**
     * Given {@code choices} of {@code Size}s supported by a camera, chooses the smallest one whose
     * width and height are at least as large as the respective requested values, and whose aspect
     * ratio matches with the specified value.
     *
     * @param choices     The list of sizes that the camera supports for the intended output class
     * @param width       The minimum desired width
     * @param height      The minimum desired height
     * @param aspectRatio The aspect ratio
     * @return The optimal {@code Size}, or an arbitrary one if none were big enough
     */
    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height, Size aspectRatio) {
    // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
    int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
    int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
    for (Size option : choices) {
        if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w &&
                option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
            bigEnough.add(option);
        }
    }

    // Pick the smallest of those, assuming we found any
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
        return choices[0];
    }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera2_video, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
    mButtonVideo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.video);
    mButtonVideo.setOnClickListener(this);
    view.findViewById(R.id.info).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startBackgroundThread();
    if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
        openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
    } else {
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    closeCamera();
    stopBackgroundThread();
    super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.video: {
            if (mIsRecordingVideo) {
                stopRecordingVideo();
            } else {
                startRecordingVideo();
            }
            break;
        }
        case R.id.info: {
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null != activity) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                        .setMessage(R.string.intro_message)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    }

    /**
     * Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void startBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
    mBackgroundThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    /**
     * Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try {
        mBackgroundThread.join();
        mBackgroundThread = null;
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    /**
     * Gets whether you should show UI with rationale for requesting permissions.
     *
     * @param permissions The permissions your app wants to request.
     * @return Whether you can show permission rationale UI.
     */
    private boolean shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(String[] permissions) {
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (FragmentCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }

    /**
     * Requests permissions needed for recording video.
     */
    private void requestVideoPermissions() {
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(VIDEO_PERMISSIONS)) {
        new ConfirmationDialog().show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
    } else {
        FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(this, VIDEO_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult");
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS) {
        if (grantResults.length == VIDEO_PERMISSIONS.length) {
            for (int result : grantResults) {
                if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.permission_request))
                            .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.permission_request))
                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
    }

    private boolean hasPermissionsGranted(String[] permissions) {
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    }

    /**
     * Tries to open a {@link CameraDevice}. The result is listened by `mStateCallback`.
     */
    private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
    if (!hasPermissionsGranted(VIDEO_PERMISSIONS)) {
        requestVideoPermissions();
        return;
    }
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == activity || activity.isFinishing()) {
        return;
    }
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "tryAcquire");
        if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
        }
        String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];

        // Choose the sizes for camera preview and video recording
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics
                .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
        mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));
        mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                width, height, mVideoSize);

        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        } else {
            mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        }
        configureTransform(width, height);
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Cannot access the camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        activity.finish();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
        // device this code runs.
        ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.camera_error))
                .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.");
    }
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
    try {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
        closePreviewSession();
        if (null != mCameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != mMediaRecorder) {
            mMediaRecorder.release();
            mMediaRecorder = null;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.");
    } finally {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
    }
    }

    /**
     * Start the camera preview.
     */
    private void startPreview() {
    if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        closePreviewSession();
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                mPreviewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                updatePreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (null != activity) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    /**
     * Update the camera preview. {@link #startPreview()} needs to be called in advance.
     */
    private void updatePreview() {
    if (null == mCameraDevice) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(mPreviewBuilder);
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
        thread.start();
        mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    private void setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(CaptureRequest.Builder builder) {
    builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    }

    /**
     * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
     * This method should not to be called until the camera preview size is determined in
     * openCamera, or until the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
     *
     * @param viewWidth  The width of `mTextureView`
     * @param viewHeight The height of `mTextureView`
     */
    private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
    float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
    float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
    if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
        bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        float scale = Math.max(
                (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
        matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
    }
    mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }

    private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    if (mNextVideoAbsolutePath == null || mNextVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()) {
        mNextVideoAbsolutePath = getVideoFilePath(getActivity());
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mNextVideoAbsolutePath);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    switch (mSensorOrientation) {
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
    }
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }

    private String getVideoFilePath(Context context) {
    return context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/"
            + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
    }

    private void startRecordingVideo() {
    if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        closePreviewSession();
        setUpMediaRecorder();
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
        List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();

        // Set up Surface for the camera preview
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
        surfaces.add(previewSurface);
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

        // Set up Surface for the MediaRecorder
        mRecorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
        surfaces.add(mRecorderSurface);
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(mRecorderSurface);

        // Start a capture session
        // Once the session starts, we can update the UI and start recording
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                mPreviewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                updatePreview();
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // UI
                        mButtonVideo.setText(R.string.stop);
                        mIsRecordingVideo = true;

                        // Start recording
                        mMediaRecorder.start();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (null != activity) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    private void closePreviewSession() {
    if (mPreviewSession != null) {
        mPreviewSession.close();
        mPreviewSession = null;
    }
    }

    private void stopRecordingVideo() {
    // UI
    mIsRecordingVideo = false;
    mButtonVideo.setText(R.string.record);
    // Stop recording
    mMediaRecorder.stop();
    mMediaRecorder.reset();

    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null != activity) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Video saved: " + mNextVideoAbsolutePath,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Video saved: " + mNextVideoAbsolutePath);
    }
    mNextVideoAbsolutePath = null;
    startPreview();
    }

    /**
     * Compares two {@code Size}s based on their areas.
     */
    static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
        // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
        return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
    }

    }

    public static class ErrorDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

    public static ErrorDialog newInstance(String message) {
        ErrorDialog dialog = new ErrorDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setMessage(getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE))
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        activity.finish();
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }

    }

    public static class ConfirmationDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Fragment parent = getParentFragment();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage(R.string.permission_request)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(parent, VIDEO_PERMISSIONS,
                                REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                parent.getActivity().finish();
                            }
                        })
                .create();
    }

    }

}
```

Reference from: [Camera2 Video](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video)

Comment: Hello, I tried this but I cannot start recording, "java.lang.IllegalStateException android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)", maybe because I'm using Lollipop Device and Camera is deprecated for versions 21 up. Thanks anyway for giving me an idea. :)

Comment: if you are using API above 21 then modify above code with camera2 API.

Comment: @Woppi I had updated answer to work with camera2 API just check it and I have also mentioned the reference. You can check that for more info.

Comment: I managed to make your first answer work in my lollipop device after removing ontouchevent and use buttons instead... Is this new answer for Camera2 only, meaning will only work for Lollipop above? The app I'm trying to build should support Jellybean up. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: wc. Happy to help.